# JPQL lexical error when trying to attach two strings in my SQL query

Tags: java, sql, jpa, oracle11g, jpql

I am basically trying to attach these two fields with a space between them on my java code (using JPA) with my oracle database.

```
Select A.name || ' ' || B.name from tableA A, tableB B where A.id = B.id;
```

I am trying to get an output like this:

"name1 name2"

This is the error message:

```
Error message: org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 21.  Encountered: "|" (124), after : ""
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder$ParsedJPQL.parse(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:2405)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder$ParsedJPQL.<init>(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:2388)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLParser.parse(JPQLParser.java:49)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ExpressionStoreQuery.newCompilation(ExpressionStoreQuery.java:154)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.newCompilation(QueryImpl.java:672)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compilationFromCache(QueryImpl.java:654)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compileForCompilation(QueryImpl.java:620)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compileForExecutor(QueryImpl.java:682)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compile(QueryImpl.java:589)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:997)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:979)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:975)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:365)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy358.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.ge.rtm.middleware.impl.RTMServiceImpl.summary(RTMServiceImpl.java:165)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:102)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.serviceRequest(JettyHTTPDestination.java:355)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:319)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1040)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:976)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:920)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: clearly there is no || operator in JPQL (as all JPQL guides would say), and I've no idea what you mean with "my SQL query" since this is not SQL. JPQL has the CONCAT function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CONCAT` instead of `||`. If you are on JPA 2, this will work

```
CONCAT(A.name, ' ', B.name)
```

On earlier JPA versions `CONCAT` only supports two parameters, so this would work

```
CONCAT(A.name, CONCAT(' ', B.name))
```

Comment: I have openjpa-2.2.2 this didn't work. It says: "Encountered "CONCAT ( S . name , \' \' ," at character 14, but expected: ["(", ")", "+", .... a long list of commands.

Comment: Can you post the actual code that caused this exception?

Comment: Tried the second suggestion and it works now. thanks.